# Is it possible to make my android application configurable from setting?

Tags: java, android

I m developing an android application.

I want to make the parameters of my android application configurable from the settings of Android

Is it possible to do that? and how I could do it?

Comment: Isn't a common **PreferenceScreen** enough for your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do that?

Only by building your own version of Android that integrates your custom change to the Settings app, then rolling your revised Android into a ROM mod, then installing that ROM mod onto your device.

Comment: I can not rebuild my android system and I do not want it. I want just to develop an android application and that application could be configurable from the settings

Comment: @MOHAMED: What you want is not possible, sorry. There are a few specific places where the Settings app will invoke an app-supplied activity (e.g., for configuring an input method editor). However, Android apps cannot otherwise inject themselves into the Settings app. Also, please bear in mind that there are dozens of implementations of the Settings app across various devices, as the Settings app is routinely rewritten and replaced by device manufacturers. The Android pattern is to provide a "settings" option in your app's action bar overflow to allow the user to configure your app.